How to pipe input to an interactive shell in Bash
I want to do something like this:
echo whoami | sh

The command whoami runs in sh, but because the pipeline as a whole runs in a subshell, the sh interpreter exits instead of giving me a shell prompt. Without using the -c argument, how can I send some input to sh and leave it running?
I need to know because sh is just an example here; I have a different program that has an interactive interpreter but doesn't have the equivalent of a -c argument.

sh -c blahblah doesn't 'leave it running' either; it executes the command(s) in blahblah and exits

That's true, but sh -c 'blahblah; sh' will give me a new shell after running the command, which is pretty much what I want.

Then so will printf '%s\n' 'blahblah' 'exec sh </dev/tty' | sh

Your echo is the problem, because it closes the pipe once it's produced the string whoami\n.
What about:
(echo whoami; cat) | sh


Ah, so my problem had nothing to do with exec. I will update the question to just be about piping to interactive shells. Thank you!

Could you remove the exec from your answer as well please?

piping the input might still make the program behave quite differently from when entering input directly from the terminal. E.g. the shells I have don't print the prompt when doing that cat | sh ... You'd need something like expect to make the program see input the same way as if you were directly on the terminal

Right, because isatty returns false because interactive input now goes through cat, so sh doesn't display $  when asking for input. That's fine for me.

@AlexHenrie OK but I think this makes the question confusing. The shell is not running in interactive mode (interactive shell in short). The noninteractive shell behaves differently in multiple other aspects too. Some examples: aliases are not evaluated, different startup scripts are run, error messages are different (they show line number)...

If you mean that sh's input should be first a pipe and then switch to being the terminal device file through which your terminal interacts, then you can use cat as Marcus has shown to forward what comes from that device file to the pipe while sh's input stays the pipe, or in the case of sh, you can tell it to reopen its stdin on the terminal device file by sending it the code to do so:
echo 'whoami; exec < /dev/tty' | sh

Note that because sh is started with something that is not a tty device as stdin, it does not enter its interactive mode operation where it outputs a prompt for instance. But you can work around that by passing the -i option:
$ echo 'whoami; exec < /dev/tty' | sh -i
$ stephane
$

Depending on the sh implementation, you may or may not see the echo of that whoami; exec < /dev/tty command line.
The above was with the dash implementation of sh. With the GNU implementation of sh (bash):
$ echo 'whoami; exec < /dev/tty' | sh -i
sh-5.2$ whoami; exec < /dev/tty
stephane
sh-5.2$

Note that /dev/tty above is a shortcut that refers to the controlling terminal of the session, easier that obtaining its actual path.
Alternatively, you can save the original stdin by duplicating it to a different fd with something like:
{ echo 'whoami; exec <&3 3<&-' | sh -i; } 3<&0

That would be cleaner as it would keep working even in contexts where that code is not run from a terminal but otherwise takes input from somewhere else.
